# Pyqt5/Pyside2 running QRegExp and QSyntaxHighlighter response very slow

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside, qregexp, syntaxhighlighter

It is a code made for identifying CEFR level of typing words. Basically frame see as below picture, I used QRegExp and QSyntaxHighlighter. The mainly function logic is through QSyntaxHighlighter to highlight specific words in the QPlaintextedit window, that specific words is a "dataframe" file storage around 46k vocabularies.

**The problem is the more words I typed, the more slower this code will perform.** like a few seconds to perform after you typed over 20 words.

I have tried using QThread(maybe used wrongly)，change faster read method(not .csv instead .jay)，change QReExp to QRegularExpression code, but none of them is worked as expected.

Now have no idea to keep through, can you help me to find out what is wrong with the code?

[image]

```py
------------
# Main code
------------
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QDialogButtonBox
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader    #Qt designer ui loader
from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon  #load icon library
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread,Signal
import enchant
import English_syntax
import PySide2

class Stats:

    def __init__(self):

        #self.ui = QUiLoader().load('ui/main_page.ui')
        self.ui =Uidocument
        self.ui.comboBox.addItems(['Standard English', 'British English', 'American English'])
        self.ui.plainTextEdit.textChanged.connect(self.cal_num)


    def Highlight(self):
        highlight = English_syntax.PythonHighlighter(Uidocument.plainTextEdit.document())

    def cal_num(self):
        text = self.ui.plainTextEdit.toPlainText()  # get text
        num = len(text)
        words = len(text.split(' '))-1 #empty is equal to 1, need to -1
        self.ui.textCount.setText(str(words)+" token(s)  " +str(num)+ " bytes")

    def handleDisplay(self,data):
        self.ui.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(data)

class Worker(QThread):
    #sig = Signal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)
        self.run()
    def run(self):
        #while True:
        highlight = English_syntax.PythonHighlighter(Uidocument.plainTextEdit.document())
        print('Connected successfully')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = 0
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setWindowIcon((QIcon('ui/images.png')))   #show icon
    Uidocument = QUiLoader().load('ui/main_page.ui')

    stats = Stats()
    #highlight = English_syntax.PythonHighlighter(Uidocument.plainTextEdit.document())
    thread = Worker()
    thread.start()

    Uidocument.show()
    # stats.ui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

```py
----------------
# English_syntax
----------------
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import QRegExp, Qt
import time


def format(color, style=''):
    """Return a QTextCharFormat with the given attributes.
    """
    _color = QtGui.QColor()
    _color.setNamedColor(color)

    _format = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
    _format.setForeground(_color)
    if 'bold' in style:
        _format.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)
    if 'italic' in style:
        _format.setFontItalic(True)

    return _format


# Syntax styles that can be shared by all languages
STYLES = {
    'A1': format('#79C740'),
    'A2': format('#CDE234'),
    'B1': format('#F0B044'),
    'B2': format('#E68237'),
    'C1': format('#D95952'),
    'C2': format('#D95999'),
    'Unrecorded': format('#9a9a9a'), #gray
    'string': format('magenta'),

}


class PythonHighlighter (QtGui.QSyntaxHighlighter):
    """Syntax highlighter for the CEFR words.
    """
    start = time.perf_counter()

    #data storage type: feather
    pathlist = "data.feather"

    pd_datas = pd.read_feather(pathlist)
    A1s = pd_datas['A1'].tolist()
    A2s = pd_datas['A2'].tolist()
    B1s = pd_datas['B1'].tolist()
    B2s = pd_datas['B2'].tolist()
    C1s = pd_datas['C1'].tolist()
    C2s = pd_datas['C2'].tolist()

    dur = time.perf_counter()-start
    print("data reading used: {:.6f}s".format(dur))
    def __init__(self, parent: QtGui.QTextDocument) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)

        start_1 = time.perf_counter()
        rules = []

        # Combine rules
        rules += [(r'\b%s\b' % q, 0, STYLES['A1'])
            for q in PythonHighlighter.A1s]
        rules += [(r'\b%s\b' % w, 0, STYLES['A2'])
            for w in PythonHighlighter.A2s]
        rules += [(r'\b%s\b' % e, 0, STYLES['B1'])
            for e in PythonHighlighter.B1s]
        rules += [(r'\b%s\b' % r, 0, STYLES['B2'])
            for r in PythonHighlighter.B2s]
        rules += [(r'\b%s\b' % t, 0, STYLES['C1'])
            for t in PythonHighlighter.C1s]
        rules += [(r'\b%s\b' % y, 0, STYLES['C2'])
            for y in PythonHighlighter.C2s]



        self.rules = [(QRegExp(pat,cs=Qt.CaseInsensitive), index, fmt)
            for (pat, index, fmt) in rules ]
        end = time.perf_counter()-start_1
        print("Analysing used: {:.6f}s".format(end))


    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        """Apply syntax highlighting to the given block of text.
        """

        # Do syntax formatting
        for expression, nth, format in self.rules:
            index = expression.indexIn(text, 0)
            #print (index)
            while index >= 0:

                s = time.perf_counter()
                # We actually want the index of the nth match
                index = expression.pos(nth)
                length = len(expression.cap(nth))
                self.setFormat(index, length, format)  #render No."index"，word lengh is "length"，to "format" type
                index = expression.indexIn(text, index + length)
                d = time.perf_counter() - s
                print("Vocabulary match used：{:.6f}s ".format(d))
                #print(index,length,format)
        self.setCurrentBlockState(0)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. Do not post it as an image, please.

Comment: Provided code : )

Comment: @Libo Using thread like this won't do anything good: 1. syntax highlighting interacts with the UI, and UI elements can only be accessed from the main thread; 2. python threading doesn't provide real concurrency for CPU bound tasks, so it would be pointless anyway. Now, it's a bit difficult to exactly understand the issue since we have no data to start with, but I suppose that each category of words has possibly hundreds, if not thousands of words. Why don't you use a dictionary with words as keys and category (or categories, if words can be part of more than one) as values?

Comment: @Libo The fact is: you have potentially thousands source words, meaning thousands rules, and you cycle through ***all** those rules for any word in the text, **every time** for **each rule**. Also, that happens not only at *every* character change in the text, but also keeps going on iterating the rules even if all words in the text block have been already found, so that's completely pointless.

Comment: @musicamante Well, thank you!  I started to notice that **every time for each rule** is really effect memory or sth, then reuslt in the problem. I have at least 46,000 source words have been sorted and apparently they will be more... Would you mind recommending me some examples of dictionary matching for me, cause I am very interested but I am a beginner.

Comment: @Libo The issue is not about memory, but performance: "how often you do the same task". The first thing you have to understand is if those words are actually unique. If they are, using a dictionary is worth a try. I never used dictionaries that big, but it certainly is an improvement: just iter through any word and use `dict.get()` to get the format (if any). It might not be "perfectly optimal", but it's better for sure: if the word is found, highlight it, otherwise go on. If the concept is that simple, then just use a set of predefined QTextCharFormat as values, and set them for each word.

Comment: @Libo Note that the above concept is still valid even for non-unique words: you could create a temporay dictionary with a list of possible categories, and then create the *final* dict based on a priority list of the categories, but using unique formats as values (and this *really* is about memory, since those formats become references). Also, be aware that such highlighting is similar to grammar checking, which is normally delayed by a timeout: it doesn't make sense to *always* check the text while typing, as it should be done *some time after* a new character has been typed.

Comment: @Libo I just did a simple test with a list of source words, counting about 475 thousand entries (all iterations of alphabet letters from 1 to 4 characters), and a simple `{word: category}` dict with two categories depending on the vowel count. It works fine even on my 10y old computer, using a 4-5k word count for paragraph. Consider that a text paragraph is normally much less than a thousand words (the standard convention is no more than 200), and `highlightBlock` is only called whenever a paragraph ("block") is changed, meaning that using a simple word based dictionary is quite sufficient.